Perl regex with Subexpression containing .* is running slow in oracle linux9 with perl 5.32.1
ts-utc!=!2024-12-26T05:38:54.649609!;!alertCount!=!0!;!alertIdName!=!TEST!;!nodeType!=!NA!;!pid!=!4091773!;!portNo!=!NA!;!location!=!A2923!;!errorMsg!=!NOT!;!

Above is input file to below Perl script which runs fine on CentOs7 Perl 5.20 but same script is taking more than 1 minute to run on Oracle Linux9 Perl 5.32.  I require help in speeding up the script.
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file='test.xml';

open my $fileH, '<', $file or die("ERROR: Unable to open file [$file]: $!");
my $aMatchString='(?=.*location!=!A2923!)(?=.*!errorMsg!=!TESTING)';

while (<$fileH>) {
# check if the string from the file matches
         if ($_ =~ m/$aMatchString/) {
             print "FOUND\n";
             print $_;
         }
         else {
             print "no found\n";
         }
     }


I am not able to reproduce the problem in an OL9 container.

Are you trying to verify that your string contains both the substrings location!=!A2923!  and !errorMsg!=!TESTING?

yes input is key value pair Key1!=!Value1!;!Key2!=!Value2!; so I want location=A2923 and errorMsg=..... Input string can have any order so I used subexpression.

Voting to close since the OP is not demonstrating the problem. They have not posted code they ran. They have no posted the data required to run it. They have not identified a problem by showing times. We have a whole lot of nothing.

Tip: ^(?s:(?=.*!location!=!A2923!).*!errorMsg!=!TESTING) would be faster

Your regex
$aMatchString='(?=.*location!=!A2923!)(?=.*!errorMsg!=!TESTING)';

In the code:
if ($_ =~ m/$aMatchString/) {

Is two lookahead assertions, non-anchorded by using .*.
This will scan every point in $_ for a location where anywhere ahead of it is either of those two strings. Which means, .* since it is greedy will absorb the whole string. Then it will go to pos EOS (end of string), check "does that begin with "l" (from "location")?" No, then go to pos EOS-1, then look for "l", then pos EOS-2, etc, until the beginning of the string, or until it finds a match. This is called backtracking. Then it will start over with the other lookahead, starting at pos EOS, and so on.
This is extremely inefficient. Though it should not be as slow as you say. But then, your code is incomplete, so you could have other code in there that slows you down further.
And it is completely unnecessary. Since regexes are not anchored to a location, you can just check for both words one at the time.
if (/location!=!A2923!/ and /!errorMsg!=!TESTING/) 

Which will first check the string for "location..." and then check the string for the "errorMsg". And combine the results. Also, it is way easier to understand.
You can even combine the logic with if-clauses
if (/location../) {
    print "Found location\n";
    if (/TESTING/) {
         print "TESTING\n";

Be careful when using .*, because it can have unexpected results for the unwary.
You also always should use use strict; use warnings; to prevent simple mistakes that take a long time to find.
In your case, if you add warnings it should say "readline() on unopened filehandle"

I updated my code, problem was I couldn't paste the complete script of 2000+ lines in this post I extracted minimum code and forgot to include open statement. Overall I found from google that .* is greedy search but why it is slowing only on linux 9 with per 5.32 is question. Is there any setting which we can turn on to speed up things.

@NIRAJ RATHI, It sounds like you're saying you never actually ran the program you posted (even after the edits). That's no good. You need to demonstrate the problem. Please provide a program you actually run, including the necessary data to replicate the problem, and the time it took for the program to run.

And at this point the posted program fails to compile because it is missing my in two places.

In general, the regex engine tries to be as efficient as it can be. You can't really expect a command option like --run-my-regex-faster-than-possible, or a pragma like use re ':faster';. Even if these existed, you would have to make a change somewhere to make use of them. Why not just replace the extremely inefficient regex with something more efficient, like this response?

@NIRAJRATHI It's impossible to show you exactly why your code of 2000+ lines is slow by only looking at 5 of those lines. Turning on a setting to speed up code is not a thing. And why should that extremely complicated solution be preferred when the solution is as simple as I made it?

@NIRAJRATHI If you're still having problems, create a short program that can be used that demonstrates the problem you are having exactly. Then post that code here. Preferably in a new question. Make sure the code you post is exactly the code you run.

In Mastering Perl I show a double lookahead assertion to a problem we posed in Learning Perl where we don't introduced lookaheads. The idea is to find a string that has two substrings, which might be in either order.
The trick is to not do it in one regex. Do it in two:
/pattern1/ && /pattern2/

For your case, you now don't need the pathologically backtracking .*. There is a quantifier modifier + to disable backtracking .*+, but I don't think that's the right solution here.
Beyond that, I'd suggest a proper parser for whatever that string is and whatever rules it has for separating keys, values, and pairs. Then, you can just ask the string if it has a key with a particular value.

and if for some reason it really has to be a single regex, it just needs to be anchored to prevent it being quadratic: '^(?=.*location!=!A2923!)(?=.*!errorMsg!=!TESTING)'
